# soundcloud API - Application Registration During Early Dev

Tags: api, soundcloud, registration

My team is experimenting with Soundcloud for the first time, and we would like to play with the API before making any strong decisions. So, we do not have an application URL or application name. From my interpretation of the registration process (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/viewform), such information is required.

Is there a way for organizations in our position to experiment extensively with the API?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to leave those fields blank and/or put in placeholder fields and I was able to use the API normally.